# Measure CPU usage of C++ and Java processes

Tags: java, c++, performance, cpu

I have an application that uses sockets and on the server side I run a java program while on the client side, a C++ program is running.

I want to measure the CPU usage of the application. Currently, I use the clock() function provided by the ctime c++ library to measure the CPU usage of my C++ program. It might be seen as a naive question but this does not include the CPU usage of its children processes, including the server side Java program, does it?

If this is not the case, is JConsole a good tool to measure CPU usage of a Java program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, clock() does not include the CPU usage of server side Java program.

You could refer [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_performance_analysis_tools#Java) for the list of java analysis tools/profilers available

Comment: Thanks @ManoNamo. This is what I had in mind to use. JConsole gets my vote.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunally, there are no program-built functions that can do this specific task.

I would reccomend you use [SIGAR API](http://support.hyperic.com/display/SIGAR/Home) for C++ it is great for checking CPU usage and also gives you the option of checking memory stats, but SIGAR API is not used for    multiple-languages.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to measure cpu usage from terminated children, then you can use `getrusage()` function. If you want to measure cpu usage in realtime then it depends on your OS. For example, if your *NIX system has support for `/proc` you can then parse data in `/proc/<PID>/stat`.

Comment: Well this is an option, but since I want to monitor the CPU usage while the program is running though the code this is not what I'm looking for especially since the ps command is a process itself and will require additional CPU